# Trying to Connect API to Angular and getting this error: TS2551: Property 'team' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'team$'?

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to connect a simple Angular app to an API and I am getting the following error:

Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:10 - error TS2551: Property 'team' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'team$'?

```
3   <h2> {{team.first_name}} - {{team._id}}</h2>
```

Any thoughts?

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Team } from './team.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/team';
  
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

getTeam() : Observable<Team[]>{
return this._http.get<Team[]>(`${this.apiUrl}`);
}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Team } from './team.model';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  team$?: Team[];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
  
  ngOnInit (){
    return this.dataService.getTeam()
    .subscribe(data => this.team$ = data);
  }
  //title = 'teamfrontend4';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor='let user of team$' style="text-align:center">
  <h2> {{team.first_name}} - {{team._id}}</h2>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are using `user` to define your variable in your `*ngFor` but then using `team` when calling it. Can you try?

```html
<div *ngFor='let user of team$' style="text-align:center">
  <h2> {{user.first_name}} - {{user._id}}</h2>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also just a note, but it's up to you, the `$` in angular is usually only used on a variable that is a subject/observable and not a value.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! This did the trick. I am new to angular, I really appreciate your time and tips.